# Anonymous Log in with Firebase (Javascript)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I know there is a way to log in anonymously with Google Firebase, but I haven't gotten it working. The issue I am having is that my app needs to be accessible on any device without logging into any account with the app.

It needs to have full control of the app's database, both reading and writing. This app isn't really meant for public use, so I am OK with anonymous authentication. I also should not have to click a button in order for it to authenticate, it should do it automatically. I tried adding the code that Google provides, but it still wont authenticate. It does work with a Google account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue related to the database rules. The default rules are set so that only authenticated users are able to read and write to the database. I set both so that anyone can read or write to the database from any device without logging in.